# Add gitlab ssh public key to known host in dockerfile behind corporate firewall (no port 22)

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to get a public key recognized in the known_hosts file within a docker build process, the relevant portion of the dockerfile I'm using being this:

```
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh

# Copy SSH host config to use port 443
COPY docker/config/gitlab_host.txt /root/.ssh/config

RUN cat ~/.ssh/config

# Download public key for gitlab.com
RUN ssh-keyscan -p443 gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

For the sake of completion, the ssh config file (`docker/config/gitlab_host.txt`):

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Firstly, I am behind a corporate firewall, no outbound traffic on port 22. Therefore we configure our ssh config to use port 443 as gitlab thankfully provides this option. However, ssh-keyscan does not seem to honour this config nor does specifying this port seem to work, there is just silent failure on the part of ssh-keyscan. I have tried multiple permutations of the command:

`ssh-keyscan -p 443 gitlab.com`
`ssh-keyscan gitlab.com:443`

All to no avail. Supplying the `-v` flag for verbosity does not generate output either.

The only other option that I can think of is copying in my own known_hosts file, does this work and is this secure? The actual cloning of repositories is done by 'passing along' the host ssh.

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,uid=1001 pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/<private>.git
RUN --mount=type=ssh,uid=1001 pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/<another_private>.git
```

What option do I have to get the host known so that I can git clone?

Comment: For port 443 the commands should be `ssh-keyscan -p 443 altssh.gitlab.com` and `pip install git+ssh://git@altssh.gitlab.com:443/`

Comment: Yes that was one of my problems. Now scanning on that url I get `0.219 getaddrinfo altssh.gitlab.com: Temporary failure in name resolutionz`. I will amend my question with this new info.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that problem as well.

When I try to get the public key with `ssh-keyscan -p 443 altssh.gitlab.com` it just stops silently and the verbose mode with `-vv` doesn't give too much information either.

I even tried to get the public key through `nmap` but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-10-20 17:09 CEST
NSE: Loaded 1 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Initiating NSE at 17:09
Completed NSE at 17:09, 0.00s elapsed
Warning: Hostname altssh.gitlab.com resolves to 26 IPs. Using 172.65.251.182.
Initiating Ping Scan at 17:09
Scanning altssh.gitlab.com (172.65.251.182) [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 17:09, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 17:09
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 17:09, 1.01s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 17:09
Scanning altssh.gitlab.com (172.65.251.182) [1 port]
Discovered open port 443/tcp on 172.65.251.182
Completed Connect Scan at 17:09, 0.00s elapsed (1 total ports)
NSE: Script scanning 172.65.251.182.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Initiating NSE at 17:09
Completed NSE at 17:09, 0.00s elapsed
Nmap scan report for altssh.gitlab.com (172.65.251.182)
Host is up, received syn-ack (0.0020s latency).
Other addresses for altssh.gitlab.com (not scanned): 172.64.33.173 173.245.59.173 108.162.193.173 173.245.58.77 108.162.192.77 172.64.32.77 173.245.59.173 108.162.193.173 172.64.33.173 108.162.192.77 172.64.32.77 173.245.58.77 2a06:98c1:50::ac40:21ad 2606:4700:58::adf5:3bad 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c1ad 2606:4700:50::adf5:3a4d 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c04d 2a06:98c1:50::ac40:204d 2606:4700:90:0:f0ff:e6a3:2ac:f7ef 2606:4700:58::adf5:3bad 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c1ad 2a06:98c1:50::ac40:21ad 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c04d 2a06:98c1:50::ac40:204d 2606:4700:50::adf5:3a4d
Scanned at 2021-10-20 17:09:01 CEST for 1s

PORT    STATE SERVICE REASON
443/tcp open  https   syn-ack

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Initiating NSE at 17:09
Completed NSE at 17:09, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.19 seconds
```

Also, I did a backup of my `known_hosts` file and I accessed through SSH to `altssh.gitlab.com:443` in order to see how the fingerprint is saved, and my surprise comes from the fact that the host, instead of being saved as `altssh.gitlab.com` is stored as `[altssh.gitlab.com]`:

I can find it with `ssh-keygen -H -F '[altssh.gitlab.com]:443'` but not as `ssh-keygen -H -F altssh.gitlab.com:443`, which would be the normal way.

I don't know the reason of this behavior, but I know that *OpenSSH 7.6* includes a new flag for adding new host keys on the first attempt, so I'm just doing once:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -p 443 git@altssh.gitlab.com
```

From the documentation of `man ssh_config`:

```
If this flag is set to “accept-new” then ssh will automatically
add new host keys to the user known hosts files, but will not
permit connections to hosts with changed host keys.
```

It will fail and it won't actually perform the connection because I'm not providing any authentication method, but the HostKey will be stored in the `known_hosts` and from that point you will be able to access with your current configuration.